# Dynamically creating new screen in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am trying to create web browser using react-native and react-native-web-view.

One of the crucial function in browser is tab feature, in which users create multiple tabs for different urls and switch between them.

The logic would be to push new screen to the navigation(without statically predefining) every time a user creates a new tab. However, navigation library like react-navigation don't allow that. You have to predefine the screens before loading the corresponding screen.

I want something in the line of...

```
const pressNewTab=()=>{
   NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: `${newRouteName}`, params: { id, ...otherParams } }),
}
```

Is there any way to achieve the feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React Navigation 5 allows you to dynamically add/remove screens: https://next.reactnavigation.org

But for your case, looks like a good way is to use a Stack navigator:

- add new screens using doing `navigation.push` with different params for each route: (e.g. `navigation.push('Tab', { url: '...' })`
- then render a custom header which shows the list of tabs

This should achieve the same behaviour as a tabbed mobile browser.

Comment: thanks, I'll look more into using params for routes! If user creates many screens this way, are they able to navigate(or jump) to other screens that are not next to each other? i.e not just using back button, but to maybe screen that they opened 5 screens before at one go.

Comment: could you please tell me how I would navigate to one of the screens I have pushed without having to pop other screens??

Answer (score 0):

I think you can probably achieve this by: 
**let's Imagine if the user has created an array of data for example**

> notes=['Note1', 'Note2', 'Note3', 'Note4']

```
class TabScreen extends Component {
   Tabs = navigation => {
    let notes=['Note1', 'Note2', 'Note3', 'Note4']
    notes = notes.reduce((val, tab) => {
      val[tab] = {
        screen: tab
      }
      return val
    }, {})

    const Tabs = createTabNavigator({
        ...notes
      },
      {
        ...TabNavigator.Presets.AndroidTopTabs,
        lazyLoad: false,
        tabBarOptions: {
          scrollEnabled: true,
          style: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.snow,
            height: Header.HEIGHT - 15
          },
          tabStyle: {
            width: 100
          },
          indicatorStyle: {
            width: 0
          }
        }
      }
    )return <Tabs />
  }

render () {
    const { navigation } = this.props
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          {this.Tabs(navigation)}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't create components in render like this because every time the component re-renders, it'll unmount and remount your navigator, losing all state.

In addition, doing it this way isn't supported in React Navigation 4. This navigator won't be connected to any other navigators, so it'll be impossible to navigate to a screen in this navigator from outside, or navigate outside from here.